# How reliable is using couplers to extend Ethernet cables?

Tags: ethernet, cables

I want to obtain one 90 meters of Ethernet CAT6 cable(with RJ45 connectors) by using three 30 meters of CAT6 cables with RJ45 connectors. The only option I could find is to use three [such](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/rj-adapters-couplers-extensions/7659031/) couplers.

Would using such extenders/couplers cause any performance or noise issues?

Comment: How fast are you actually expecting to send data over the resulting cable?

Comment: What insertion loss does it cause?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Here is the device: http://scanivalve.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/MPS4264_1703.pdf But it doesn't say anything about the rate but something called "Data Output Rate"

Comment: 10/100/1000MBps which?

Comment: I am wondering why three couplers would be needed. Joining three cables only requires two couplers.  RJ45---cable---RJ45 COUPLER RJ45---cable---RJ45 COUPLER RJ45---cable---RJ45

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a coupler exactly like that one, but I did try using the one below (from Belkin and Monoprice). Out of 8 that I've bought 5 did not work at all. The other three worked... sort of. Even small wiggling of the cable would often break a connection. I ended up buying a whole pull-box of CAT6 and a pack of crimp plugs.

[image]

Oh, and in one place where I had to use a socket I've used tool-less Keystone below. It works flawlessly at 1G for many years now. I guess you can make your own coupler out of two sockets like that one. Or **cut the plugs off one end of two 30m cables and replace them with sockets**, effectively converting patch cable into extension cable. Note that this will also cut the number of contact pairs in half, improving line integrity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable

> **Maximum length**
>       When used for 10/100/1000BASE-T, the maximum allowed length of a Cat 6 cable is up to **100 meters** (328 ft). This consists of 90 meters
>   (295 ft) of solid "horizontal" cabling between the patch panel and the
>   wall jack, plus 5 meters (16 ft) of stranded patch cable between each
>   jack and the attached device.[8] For 10GBASE-T, an unshielded Cat 6
>   cable should not exceed 55 meters.[9]

Its possible.